# How to catch div height in each and set in another each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a simple markup example, like this:

```
<div class="question-child">question 1</div>
<div class="question-child">question 2</div>
<div class="question-child">question 3</div>
<div class="question-child">question 4</div>

<div class="answer-child">answer 1</div>
<div class="answer-child">answer 2</div>
<div class="answer-child">answer 3</div>
<div class="answer-child">answer 4</div>
```

So, this `divs` are in foreach of php.
I need the `divs:answer-child` have the same height of `divs:question-child`. Because the `divs:question-child` change height according your content. (like a table row)

I tried to use `$().each`, but I do not know if I'm doing the right way.
Can help me?

**===UPDATE===**
With the help of @Florin Pop, we managed to accomplish each to sweep the divs as I said. But now I have another problem - which was to have mentioned here before.
As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/9/), the `div:all` involves all the questions and answers, and the same is repeated. The big problem are the titles. They also vary in height, like the divs in my previous question.
How to make the size of the `divs:old-title` have the same size of `divs:current-title` ???

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `.each` method. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
$(".answer-child").each(function(e){
    $(this).css("height", $(".question-child").eq(e).css("height"));
});
```

I've also created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/749n6zag/3/).

**UPDATE:**
Based on the OP question in the comments. The answer for this html structure:

```
<div class="question-child">question 1</div>
<div class="question-child">question 2</div>
<div class="question-child">question 3</div>
<div class="question-child">question 4</div>

<div class="answer-parent">
    <div class="answer-child">answer 1</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 2</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 3</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 4</div>
</div>

<div class="answer-parent">
    <div class="answer-child">answer 1</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 2</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 3</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 4</div>
</div>

<div class="answer-parent">
    <div class="answer-child">answer 1</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 2</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 3</div>
    <div class="answer-child">answer 4</div>
</div>
```

is this jQuery code:

```
$(".question-child").each(function(e){
    var that = $(this);
    $(".answer-parent").each(function(){
        $(this).children(".answer-child").eq(e).css("height", that.css("height"));
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/9h04Lhww/4/).

**UPDATE 2:**

For the title issue, please add this code to your already existing jQuery code:

```
var title_height = $(".current-title").eq(0).css("height");
$(".old-title").css("height", title_height);
```

jsfiddle for the title-issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/10/).

Comment: OP wants to set the height of answer div(s), not the question div(s).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Parkash, I've changed the code :)

Comment: @FlorinPop its great. Worked for me. But, i have a another doubt: And if i have a foreach to repeat the divs:answer-child, how do i do? Visit my jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/2/)

Comment: @ADHenrique is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @FlorinPop YEEEEES ITS VERY GREAT! :D Now I am trying to use your code to another solution, but I can not :S.
As can be seen in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/6/), each of these divs are engaged by a principal and this have a title.

Comment: @FlorinPop Div:current are the answers in the current moment. But the div:old, are divs containing earlier responses, answered by the user.
I want to make the same adjust for divs:old-title, catching the height of divs:current-title.
I used the same code that you answered, but does not worked.
It would be too much to ask your help again?

Comment: So you want the 2 old-title divs to be same height as the current-title div?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/7/ 
Hope it helps. This is basic jQuery, you should know this little.

Comment: Sorry, @FlorinPop I forgot to put the correct update jsFiddle in my comment. :S
My situation is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/8/). All These divs are repeated.
Look to the div.all.

Comment: I don't understand... I'm sorry

Comment: Sorry @FlorinPop . The div:current-title change height according your content. (like a table row too). So, the div:all repeat in foreach of php, but the titles are diferent in text and height. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9h04Lhww/9/)

Comment: @FlorinPop If i use the `$(".old-title").css('height','xx')`, the titles will all have the same height, but they vary dynamically. I need to use `$().each` also, no?

Comment: @AD Henrique, When asking question, one should try to explain his / her issues or requirements in just fewer request. Asking again and again for the changes require efforts and answer-er's time as well. As a good questioner, you should have asked for these changes earlier on.

Comment: @ParkashKumar yes, i know. My mistake, sorry =(
I'm trying to work here. If case I find a solution, put the answer here!

Comment: @ParkashKumar I updated my question. Thanks for the information.